# A software to draw an algorithm

Tags: software-rec, drawing, algorithm

I'm currently working on a complex algorithm, and I want to draw it into a reference document.

Basically, I have formulas, formulas are linked to their operands, operands are formulas themselves linked to sub-operands... And among this, I have "decisions" (switch/case branching) and data matrix.

I've been using OOO draw with embedded calc objects, so far. But I'm still not completely satisfied, as some matrix are huge.

Would you know by chance a software that makes the following easier to draw ?

An algorithm with formulas, decisions and data matrix with ooo draw :

- http://www.dropbox.com/s/xuwh8030egwzu6k/algorithm.png

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [labview](http://sine.ni.com/np/app/flex/p/docid/nav-104/lang/nl/) then, it's a visual programming language that allows you to do just that iirc.